# Oracle Merge - constraint violation on unique key

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have this table in oracle 11g.

```
TABLE: ORDER_LOCK
Name                   Null     Type                
---------------------- -------- ----------          
ORDER_ID                     NOT NULL NUMBER(10) [PRIMARY KEY] 
ORDER_REF_ID                 NUMBER(10)          [UNIQUE KEY]
ORDER_MSG_SENT                   NUMBER(1)          


merge into ORDER_LOCK al 
using ( select ? ORDER_REF_ID, ? ORDER_MSG_SENT from dual ) t 
on (al.ORDER_REF_ID = t.ORDER_REF_ID) 
when not matched then 
    insert (ORDER_ID, ORDER_REF_ID, ORDER_MSG_SENT) 
    values (ORDER_LOCK_SEQ.nextval, t.ORDER_REF_ID, t.ORDER_MSG_SENT)
```

I am using the above Merge from my applications (Java). The merge call happens from multiple threads. The code has been working fine but yesterday we got a constraint violation (ORA-00001) on the unique key 'ORDER_REF_ID'.

Is there a problem with the Merge statement? or, Is there any specific scenario when the above Merge statement may result in a constraint violation?

Thanks

Pushkar

Comment: Did you check whether two or more threads might by trying to insert the same order_ref_id?

Answer (score 2):

This will happen if you have two sessions (in your case, Java threads) that try to insert the same ORDER_REF_ID. Consider the following scenario:

1) Session 1 executes this MERGE statement (without committing it):

```
merge into ORDER_LOCK al 
using ( select 1 ORDER_REF_ID, sysdate ORDER_MSG_SENT from dual ) t 
on (al.ORDER_REF_ID = t.ORDER_REF_ID) 
when not matched then 
    insert (ORDER_ID, ORDER_REF_ID, ORDER_MSG_SENT) 
    values (ORDER_LOCK_SEQ.nextval, t.ORDER_REF_ID, t.ORDER_MSG_SENT);
```

2) Session 2 starts the same MERGE statement:

```
merge into ORDER_LOCK al 
using ( select 1 ORDER_REF_ID, sysdate ORDER_MSG_SENT from dual ) t 
on (al.ORDER_REF_ID = t.ORDER_REF_ID) 
when not matched then 
    insert (ORDER_ID, ORDER_REF_ID, ORDER_MSG_SENT) 
    values (ORDER_LOCK_SEQ.nextval, t.ORDER_REF_ID, t.ORDER_MSG_SENT);
```

(this will try to insert the row, since Session 2 doesn't "see" the uncommitted changes from Session 1. Session 2 will block, since it is waiting for the lock held by Session 1):

3) Session 1 commits

=> Session 2 now tries to perform the insert, which will raise an ORA-00001: UNIQUE CONSTRAINT VIOLATION since the ORDER_REF_ID 1 already exists

**UPDATE**

To fix this problem, I'd suggest you modify your application and introduce some kind of affinity between Java threads and ORDER_REF_IDs - each ORDER_REF_ID should "belong" to exactly one thread, and that thread should exclusively insert / update data for its ORDER_REF_ID.

Comment: Thanks Frank. The insert which the Merge statement is doing is conditional, i.e. when the ORDER_REF_ID is not found in the table , it does the insert. If the ORDER_REF_ID is found in the table it does not do the insert. Am I missing something here? The Merge was specifically implemented to avoid the ORA-00001.

Comment: You cannot avoid the ORA-00001 if two sessions are trying to insert at the same time, unless you change the Transaction isolation level to "READ UNCOMMITTED" (definitely *not* recommended). The most sensible thing to do if your MERGE encounters an ORA-00001 is a ROLLBACK and re-trying the operation - if the first session has committed in the meantime, the second session won't try to perform the insert.

Comment: What's your opinion on https://markhoxey.wordpress.com/2015/04/15/ora-00001-unique-key-violated-with-merge/ ?